# JSF2 xhtml Date formatting and sorting

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

So I am receiving date in String format.

example : `2014-10-06T16:30:08.000+03:00`

Temporary work around was just to use `substring` and `replace`, but

now I need to `sort` messages, using this date.

Example output:

Instead of: `2014-10-06T16:30:08.000+03:00`  `Message1`

I would like to get: `2014-10-06 16:30  Message 1`

If there is a chance to stay with String format and use `substring` and sort it by date, That's would be fine.

**EDIT**: stuff like `<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>`
doesn't work.

Comment: What about use proper pattern for `convertDateTime`?

Comment: Any ideas r welcome..

Comment: Pattern should be like "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSX". But it works for formatting Date. In your case data is String. You can convert it in Java via `SimpleDateFormat`and use result for sorting, ...